# Node from which Package is running now?

Tags: ros, package, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

there are some node running, i saw them in rqt_graph. but how can i find where they are runned from which ros package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59194/node-from-which-package-is-running-now?/) by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-03-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know this info is not published although it's there.

Possible ways to solve your problem:

- do a `rosnode info` and then search for the node name on the internet
- open the launch file (if any) and look at the package the node is launched from

---

Originally posted by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) with karma: 859 on 2013-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1